# Jquery form Insert Mode To ReadOnly Mode To Edit Mode

Tags: jquery, mode

Does anybody know where to find a good jquery plugin for switching form from view mode to edit mode?

Thanks & Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is all good, I found this http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable to be very helpful.

The following article is excellent !